# VB 2010 : what are the codes for textbox that allows both letters,spaces and punc.marks only

Tags: vb.net, ascii, keypress

we're working on our capstone project and we're having a little trouble in coding for text box in MS Visual Studio 2010 .. i want my text box to accept letters, commas, periods and spaces as well (not numbers) .. my text box is for entering student name and numbers should not allowed on this text box . Is there someone out there who can be a big help for this ???  thanks in advance !!!

```
    If Not Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) And Not e.KeyChar = Chr(Keys.Delete) And Not e.KeyChar = Chr(Keys.Back) Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
```

here's our code but it only accepts letter but the spaces are not allowed .. please can you help me out for this ?

Answer (score 1):

The code below might help you.

```
Dim allowedChars as String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,. "

If allowedChars.IndexOf(e.KeyChar) = -1
    If Not e.KeyChar = Chr(Keys.Back) Then
        e.Handled = True
        Beep()
    End If
End If
```

Implement this code in KeyPress Event of textBox.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this ..

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress

    Dim sN As String = "0123456789"   

    If sN.Contains(e.KeyChar) Then

        e.Handled = True   

    End If

End Sub
```